# Split RadioButtons/Checkbox into 2 columns

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a lot of `RadioButtons` and `Checkboxes` and I basically want to split them in a second Column, to  make it look more user friendly. I found some examples but not really for `WPF`.

**Picture of Buttons**

[image: Picture of Buttons]

and this is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AuswahlOptionenViewModelCollection}"  Margin="115,50,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="antwortmoeglichkeiten:OptionViewModel">
                <Viewbox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignUserForegroundCheckBox}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                              Command="{Binding SelectedOptionViewModelCommand}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"
                              Content="{Binding Value}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change ItemsPanel and use UniformGrid with 2 columns:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```